# Storing Packet Capture Files In Database

Tags: database, pcap

I am trying to store packet capture files into a database, and I am running into problems with performance.

Here are some of my goals (in order of priority)
1) Store individual packet frames in database and be able to search for them using at least their time stamp
2) Store packet captures as they are received (Let's say, at a rate of at least a few hundred packets per second)
3) Filter and search through packets for patterns (size, duration, tcp or udp, etc.)

At first, I thought that I would be best off using a Time Series database like InfluxDB, but I then realized that I would need to search on fields other than time, making this less effective.  Then, I tried parsing all of the fields into a packet dump xml file (pdml) using tshark and then storing them into a NoSQL database (elasticsearch), but this proved to be exceptionally slow.

Here is my question: 
1) What are some efficient database options for storing packet capture data?  Am I better off with SQL or NoSQL database?

2) How can I save an individual packet to a database? I can't find a way to get individual packets from tshark, bro, snort, or other packet analyzers from the command line?

3) Are there any other options for parsing the packets to a useful datbase format?  I was thinking of extracting fewer fields using tshark; I suppose I don't need all of them.

Any help, thoughts, or ideas would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: Disregard 2, I found the format of the pcap file here and then parsed int manually: [link](http://systemsarchitect.net/parsing-binary-data-in-php-on-an-example-with-the-pcap-format/)

Comment: What kind of volume are you talking about? Would it be reasonable to buffer a group of packets then insert them as a batch, or even capture the whole sequence to a file and post-process into the DB?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what the volume will be, but I am estimating at least a few megabytes per second. Additionally I did end up adding support for buffering the packets into groups and batch inserting as this ended up being plenty efficient. To be honest my question is no longer relevant as I am too far past the point to redesign my approach, but thank you anyway.  I would particularly appreciate a mac alternative to jlibpcap, though....